# Hover only some combined DIV-Boxes in a row

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a boxset that are composed of 2 bootstrap columns each forming a box in a 4-column container.

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3 box-left">Image 1</div>
  <div class="col-md-3 box-right">Text 1</div>
  <div class="col-md-3 box-left">Image 2</div>
  <div class="col-md-3 box-right">Text 2</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
...
```

The left two form a combined box as well as the right two, looks like:
( Image1 | Text1 ) ( Image2 | Text2 )

Is it possible to let only the first OR the second box completely hover when only one of the involved elements is overrun with the mouse?
I tried this:

```css
.row:hover .box-left {
  background-color: #d3ecfb;
}
.row:hover .box-right {
  background-color: #d3ecfb;
}
```

but then all 4 colums (that means both combines boxes in this row) hover; that's logical, but I don't succeed in selecting only 2 at a time...
Tried jquery, too:-

```
$(".navi-box-left:first-child").hover(...
```

But then ALL the left boxes in ALL `.row hover`
Have made experiments with `nextsibling` etc., but I'm not experienced enough for this :
thanks and nice regards...

Comment: Having the right box change when the left one gets hovered would be possible using CSS alone, but the other direction is not technically possible the same way. In some situations the visual effect can be achieved using rather complex workarounds. Of course putting only one left and right box into a `.row` each (instead of four of them) would quite easily solve your problem here, and reason you did not do that?

Comment: ok - the .row ist from a Bootstrap-setup. Using a new row will cause a new line (this is not desired). Also the possibility to put another div between row and col doesn't work. Behind it there is already a css which doesn't (anymore) work properly in this case...

Comment: Ah, you still want them all next to each other, okay. That would justify a row with two columns then, that contain a row with two columns each. You simply apply your hover formatting based on hovering the inner rows then. _“Behind it there is already a css which doesn't (anymore) work properly in this case...”_ - this is not such a massive change in structure, that it should cause an enormous amount of rewriting in the CSS as well … probably done by modifying a few selectors accordingly. (But that really all depends on the specifics.)

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problem is that you apply the `::hover` on the full `.row`

If I understood what you want, an easy fix would be to group each pair in a div with a dedicated class and to apply the `::hover` on this class :

the html

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="col-md-3 box-left">Image 1</div>
    <div class="col-md-3 box-right">Text 1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="col-md-3 box-left">Image 2</div>
    <div class="col-md-3 box-right">Text 2</div>
  </div>
<div class="row">
```

and in the css

```css
.row .box:hover {
  background-color: #d3ecfb;
}
```

**_ edit 1 _**
(deleted edit because it was completely false)

**_ edit 2 _**

Here is a workaround in js (sorry I am no jQuery user)

It groups every **box-left** with the next sibling **box-right** and insert them in a div of class **box** inserted in the parent...
Not the cleanest way but it works : https://codepen.io/gui3/pen/zYYeZRW

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".box-left").forEach(element=> {
  var sibling = element.nextElementSibling;
  if (sibling.classList.contains("box-right")) {
    var parent = element.parentNode;
    var box = parent.appendChild(
      document.createElement("div")
    );
    box.appendChild(element);
    box.appendChild(sibling);
    box.classList.add("box");
  }
})
```

and now the css

```css
.box:hover {
  background-color: #2980b9;
}
```

Comment: yes, that's obvious and was already recommended above. However, there is already a large database in which many such pages are stored (should be transferred into a new project without conversion if possible). Usind this solution, I have to write a converter or change all of it manually :( ...

Comment: in addition a lot of adjusted css doesn't work correctly anymore concerning the positioning of the boxes; ok - thats a minor problem.
My hope was a solution in js/jquery maybe...

Comment: You say that you cannot change the html ? that's a game changer indeed. Sorry I didn't get that.

Comment: ok only inserting a new DIV level would be a pain in the a... Adding a new class to the col's could be done easily by SQL-Replace - BUT: trying this solution, only the left or the right part of a combined box hovers, not the whole box?!??

Comment: ok Gui3 - thanks for your effort first! But this solution with injecting an additional DIV messes up the Bootstrap setup in the same way as when i'm doing it directly in the code. in addition the background of the new DIV box hovers, not the two parts of the box itself...
By the way - the link to the codepen is the same as the below one from mohammed??? I didn' see your solution there...

Comment: sorry here is my fork of Mohammed's codepen https://codepen.io/gui3/pen/zYYeZRW

Answer (score 0):

ok, found a solution.
Maybe not the most elegant way, but to everyone who's interested and/or have a similar problem - the following jquery does the trick:

```js
$(function() {
    $(".box-left").hover(  // If ANY left part is overrun change ONLY this + next
      function() {
        $(this).css('background-color','#d3ecfb');
        $(this).next().css('background-color','#d3ecfb');
      },
      function() {
        $(this).css('background-color','#eee');
        $(this).next().css('background-color','#eee');
      }
    );
    $(".box-right").hover(  // If ANY right part is overrun change ONLY this + previous
      function() {
        $(this).css('background-color','#d3ecfb');
        $(this).prev().css('background-color','#d3ecfb');
      },
      function() {
        $(this).css('background-color','#eee');
        $(this).prev().css('background-color','#eee');
      }
    );
  });
```

Answer (score -1):

we can select two child by using nth method 
check this
[codepen](https://codepen.io/DDAF/pen/JjjxbPz)

```
 .col-md-3:nth-child(-n + 2):hover {
  background-color: #2980b9;
  }
```

Comment: Wrong syntax (colon at the end of `.row:` makes no sense), and not even what was asked about here in the first place.

Comment: ok, tried ist (without unterstanding it well) - but only the left or the right part of the first box hovers?!...